# Android ListView Background not painted

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm working on the UI for an application I'm writing but I've hit a bit of a wall and wonder if there is anyone out there can give me some advice.

I've created a ViewFlipper to slide between two ListViews. It works well enough so far however there seems to be an issue with drawing.

The ListView has a background, the rows are transparent. When I select a row and the slide to the next list occurs the rows turn (I think) transparent, then the ListView background is painted once the animation stops. What is odd however is that the space below the rows do not turn transparent.

It's a bit hard to explain so I recorded a video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fEEf6_DyPo

If I put a background on the rows then they do not turn transparent.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find it does this when scrolling too. Try setting "android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" on your listview.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked. Can you explain what that does and why it works? I can't mark your answer as the 'answer' for another 7 mins but I will.

Comment: No problem. Cache colour hint is used by android to optimise the drawing speed during animation - it's faster to draw a solid colour than using transparency. Setting it to "#00000000" ensures it remains transparent during animations. If you use a solid background behind your listview, ensure to set the hint to that colour for optimal performance.

Comment: it sets the background color of the listview transparent. The ARGB value indicates that the first two 00 sets the alpha layer to 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to rendering issue caused by an optimization of the Android framework

To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000

Refer this link for more details ...
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html