# Android setting ListView background programmatically with transparency issues

Tags: android

My first question is, how do I set the color of the listview background as white?

I tried list.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF); but of course that doesn't work.

Another issue I've been having with other listviews (I can easily change the bg in xml, but I dont know how in java) is that the rows turn black when you tap and scroll.

I think this is the problem: [Android ListView Background not painted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160332/android-listview-background-not-painted)

Again, I have no clue as to how I implement it in my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the background color of listview as follows,

```
  ListView listview=new ListView(this);
  listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If your listview shows black when you scrolling the listview then add the some code in xml as

```
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

I think it may helpful to you.

Edit:

```
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/plainbg">


 <ListView 
 android:id="@+id/foodlistview"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
 android:divider="@android:color/white"
 android:dividerHeight="2px"
 ></ListView>
```

Here the xml layout contains listview.

Comment: Can I set the cacheColorHint in java? I dont really want to create an xml just for this.

Comment: yes you can set in java. listview.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE); for listview in xml check my answer in edit section.

Answer (score 5):

For setting the background you can use:

```
listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.COLOR_YOU_PICK);
```

or:

```
listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fff0f0f0"));
```

As far as the blackbackround goes use this on your listview:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setCacheColorHint` too - that should fix both of these problems.